# Why does Ruby have no !== operator?

Tags: ruby

Is *all* equality in Ruby is "strict", analogous to `===` in PHP? I notice that there is a `===` operator in Ruby but it does something different.

Comment: A quick googling determines it's for a when clause, so if I had a best-guess it'd be that they just didn't add a `!==` for that.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with PHP, please explain what a `!==` operator would return and what you mean by "strict", preferably by editing the question. Would this have to do with objects being the same versus values being the same?

Answer (score 8):

`===` is not an equality operator!

Not.

But, what is it?

You might be familiar with `===` as an equality operator in Javascript and PHP, but this just not an equality operator in Ruby and has fundamentally different semantics from other languages.

So what does `===` do?

`===` is the pattern matching operator!

- `===` matches regular expressions
- `===` checks range membership
- `===` checks being instance of a class
- `===` calls lambda expressions
- `===` sometimes checks equality, but mostly it does not

So how does this madness make sense?

- `Enumerable#grep` uses `===` internally
- `case when` statements use `===` internally

That is why you can use regular expressions and classes and ranges and even lambda expressions in a `case when` statement.

Some examples

```
case value
when /regexp/
  # value matches this regexp
when 4..10
  # value is in range
when MyClass
  # value is an instance of class
when ->(value) { ... }
  # lambda expression returns true
when a, b, c
  # value matches one of a, b, c with `===`
when *array
  # value matches an element in array with `===`
when x
  # values is equal to x unless x is one of the above
end
```

All these example work with `pattern === value` too, as well as with `grep` method.

I can only guess why there's no `!==` method but Tadman's intuition seems spot on, `===` is mostly used indirectly through `case when` and `grep` and thus likely didn't seem to need an explicit inverse operator. Most style guides for production code ban the use of `===` operator anyway.

If you are looking for other equality operators, check `.eql?` and `.equal?`

Answer (score 3):

Ruby doesn't need a strict `===`-type operator because the default comparator `==` is already quite strict, unlike PHP and others. It's not often the case any sort of conversion is done, so the cases where it is performed stand out as exceptional:

```
0 == ""
# => false

0 == "0"
# => false

"" == " "
# => false

0 == nil
# => false

0 == 0.0
# => true
```

In fact when you *do* use `===` you're often asking for trouble by being overly specific or inviting unexpected behaviour:

```
"" === String
# => false

String === ""
# => true

String === Object
# => false

Object === String
# => false
```

The meaning of `===` is defined by various classes in different ways to mean things often unrelated to "equality". It's just a shorthand like `<<` is at times. `Object === String` is actually `Object.===(String)` which is why it produces different results from `String.===(Object)`. In that case it means "is equal to or a derived class of...".

It's because of this relative rarity that `!==` doesn't really need to exist in the first place. `===` is often used only indirectly, as it's the default method for comparing things via a `case` statement.

Comment: @akuhn Gave it a bit of a rewrite there.

Answer (score 1):

Ah... after digging deeper I think I answered my own question. Ruby has `.eql?` `.equal?` [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's equality is not strict using `==`, at least not like `===` in JavaScript. Ruby has stricter equality methods, such as `eql?` and `equal?`, but the `===` is not for strict equality. The `===` method is called the *subsumption* operator. It's most used implicitly in `case` statements. This is to say that

```
case a 
when b ...
when c ...
else ...
end
```

is equivalent to

```
if b === a
...
elsif c === a
...
else
...
end
```

Having said that, `!==` could exist, but instead it is just left for the user to do `!(a === b)`. Note that `===` is not commutative as in `a === b` is not the same as `b === a`.

Comment: There's a lot of reasons why `===` should not be used unless you know exactly what you're doing.